# config.properties and hibernate configuration xml

Tags: hibernate, configuration-files

I was going through a sample spring-hibernate example source code in Eclipse. Here the database and hibernate configuration are written in `config.properties` under `resources` folder. And in some other examples I saw these configurations are done in the hibernate configuration xml files.I just confused on seeing this. Is there any difference in doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate let you decide how you are going to configure database information and so on. It could be either XML or properties file format. It is up to you which one you prefer to go with.